# Rellenar datos de form con un ngFor y FormControl

Tags: angular, typescript

estoy haciendo una práctica de un crud, y todo va bien, estoy haciendo la parte de un update, y mi idea es que cuando le piquemos al botón de editar se carguen unos formularios con los inputs llenos de cada dato, ejemplo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y lo que intento hacer es que esos datos de grade y name se llenen, en mi ts relleno un array desde la base datos y solo trae los atributos name y grade

```
users:User[]
modUsr = new FormGroup({
  name: new FormControl( '', Validators.required),
  grade : new FormControl( '', Validators.required)
})
```

Y en el html los cargo asi:

```
<form [formGroup]="modUsr" (ngSubmit)="modUser()" style="display:grid; width:30%; margin: 10px;" 
*ngFor="let user of users" >
<label for="name">Name</label>
<input type="text" name="name" value="{{user.name}}" formControlName="name">
<div *ngIf="name">
   <p style="color:red;">Error en nombre</p>
</div>
<label for="grade">Grade</label>
<input type="number" name="grade" value="{{user.grade}}" formControlName="grade">
<div *ngIf="grade">
  <p style="color:red;">Error en grado</p>
</div>
<button type="submit"> Ingresar Usuario </button>
</form>
```

Pero no imprime ningún valor, y no se si sea por la declaración del formControl o algo, y estuve revisando la documentación pero mas me confundí

Comment: Te recomiendo cambiar en cada input el `value` a `[value]=user.name` en el caso del `name`